# List index out of range error on simple python for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Can someone explain to me why this for loop doesn't work. I'm trying to use something like this in another program to loop through a list using this N as a parameter.

```
    N = [20,40,60,80]

    for j in N:
        print(j)
        for i in range(0,N[j]):
            print(i)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your goal here?

Comment: why it doesn't work? what result do you expect ?

Comment: N is the number of balls bouncing around in a simulated box. The end goal is to calculate the pressure exerted under different temperatures with different numbers of balls. But for some reason I'm stuck on this seemingly simple list error

Comment: `j` is value from `N`, not `index` so you get `N[80]` but `N` doesn't so many elements. - use `range(0, j)`

Comment: @furas it tells me that "for i in range(0,N[j]):" is a IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: use `range(0, j)`

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help guys. @furas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're out of range, because j is taking the values of the elements of the N array, not the index. So, j is not 0, 1, 2, 3 but rather 20, 40, 60, 80.
So, when you get to `for i in range((0, N[j])`, you're asking for N[20], which is well beyond the length of the N list.

You could do:

```
N = [20,40,60,80]

for j in range(len(N)):
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    print(j)
    for i in range(0,N[j]):
        print(i)
```

Comment: Glad it helped. If you like my answer, please select it, and go back to studying! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for i in range(0,j):
```

Instead of:

```
for i in range(0,N[j]):
```

Since `N[j]` will access way beyond whats in the list, such as `N[80]`, which doesn't exist. This is why you're getting a `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

To fix this, you need to apply `range()` on your outer loop:

```
for i in range(len(N)):
    print(i)
    for j in range(0, N[i]):
        print(j)
```

Which only looks at the indexes `i` of `N` when applying it to `range()` in the inner loop, instead of the actual elements, which are a lot larger.

If you want to access whats actually in the list with respect to an index, try this:

```
N = [20,40,60,80]
for i in range(len(N)):
    print(i, "->", N[i])
```

Which outputs:

```
0 -> 20
1 -> 40
2 -> 60
3 -> 80
```

If you want just the numbers:

```
for number in N:
    print(number)
```

If you want both the index and the number in a more pythonic manner:

```
for index, number in enumerate(N):
    print(index, "->", number)
```

Which outputs:

```
0 -> 20
1 -> 40
2 -> 60
3 -> 80
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use enumerate

```
N = [20,40,60,80]
for index, j in enumerate(N):
    print(j)
    for i in range(0,N[index]):
        print(i)
```